# NVD3 Multiple Axis Barchart Overlapping Bars on Drawing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

Drawing a Multiple Axis barchart using nvd3. My problem is the bars are overlapping. In the chart on y-axis is on left side and the other y-axis on right side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.3/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.3/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <style>
        text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }
        svg {
            display: block;
        }
        html, body, #chart1, svg {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>

<div id="chart1" >
    <svg> </svg>
</div>

<script>

    // var testdata = stream_layers(9,10+Math.random()*100,.1).map(function(data, i) {
    //     return {
    //         key: 'Stream' + i,
    //         values: data.map(function(a){a.y = a.y * (i <= 100 ? 100 : 1); return a})
    //     };
    // });
     var testdata=[{"key":"stream1", "values": [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 44
    },
    {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 10
    },
    {
      "x": 2,
      "y": 29
    },
    {
      "x": 3,
      "y": 88
    },
    {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 25
    },
    {
      "x": 5,
      "y": 32
    },
    {
      "x": 6,
      "y": 100
    },
    {
      "x": 7,
      "y": 52
    },
    {
      "x": 8,
      "y": 15
    },
    {
      "x": 9,
      "y": 78
    },
    {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 42
    },
    {
      "x": 11,
      "y": 108
    },
    {
      "x": 12,
      "y": 17
    },
    {
      "x": 13,
      "y": 23
    },
    {
      "x": 14,
      "y": 182
    },
    {
      "x": 15,
      "y": 9
    },
    {
      "x": 16,
      "y": 25
    },
    {
      "x": 17,
      "y": 90
    },
    {
      "x": 18,
      "y": 32
    },
    {
      "x": 19,
      "y": 138
    },
    {
      "x": 20,
      "y": 189
    },
    {
      "x": 21,
      "y": 3
    },
    {
      "x": 22,
      "y": 16
    },
    {
      "x": 23,
      "y": 66
    },
    {
      "x": 24,
      "y": 46
    },
    {
      "x": 25,
      "y": 27
    },
    {
      "x": 26,
      "y": 185
    },
    {
      "x": 27,
      "y": 13
    },
    {
      "x": 28,
      "y": 12
    },
    {
      "x": 29,
      "y": 71
    },
    {
      "x": 30,
      "y": 191
    }
  ]},
  {"key":"stream2","values":[
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 1.1
    },
    {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": 2,
      "y": 2.1
    },
    {
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1.5
    },
    {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 1.7
    },
    {
      "x": 5,
      "y": 2.1
    },
    {
      "x": 6,
      "y": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": 7,
      "y": 1.75
    },
    {
      "x": 8,
      "y": 1
    },
    {
      "x": 9,
      "y": 2.3
    },
    {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 2
    },
    {
      "x": 11,
      "y": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": 12,
      "y": 1.6
    },
    {
      "x": 13,
      "y": 1.8
    },
    {
      "x": 14,
      "y": 2.35
    },
    {
      "x": 15,
      "y": 2.4
    },
    {
      "x": 16,
      "y": 1.8
    },
    {
      "x": 17,
      "y": 1
    },
    {
      "x": 18,
      "y": 1.25
    },
    {
      "x": 19,
      "y": 1.85
    },
    {
      "x": 20,
      "y": 0.65
    },
    {
      "x": 21,
      "y": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": 22,
      "y": 1.25
    },
    {
      "x": 23,
      "y": 2.25
    },
    {
      "x": 24,
      "y": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": 25,
      "y": 1.85
    },
    {
      "x": 26,
      "y": 1.75
    },
    {
      "x": 27,
      "y": 1.15
    },
    {
      "x": 28,
      "y": 1.9
    },
    {
      "x": 29,
      "y": 2.4
    },
    {
      "x": 30,
      "y": 1.5
    }
  ]}];
    testdata[0].type = "bar";
    testdata[0].yAxis = 1;
    testdata[1].type = "bar";
    testdata[1].yAxis = 2;
    console.log(testdata);

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
            .height(450)
            .width(1200)
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .interpolate('linear');

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
        chart.yAxis1.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
        chart.yAxis2.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

        d3.select('#chart1 svg')
            .datum(testdata)
            .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

        return chart;
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A Plunkr setup [embeded](http://embed.plnkr.co/IBfexxM81dg9Bh1UrvAE/)  for this can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBfexxM81dg9Bh1UrvAE?p=preview).

Two set of data to draw the multi graph But the bars are overlapping. My Out put screen shot is here.

[image: Screenshot of Barchart with two y-axes and different data range.]

the only thing to do is to adjust the width and position of bars. those are selectable by the class

```
d3.selectAll ('.bars1Wrap .nv-groups .nv-series-0 rect')
```

When I switch the axis to

```
testdata[1].yAxis = 1;
```

It works perfect.
[image: Graph with one y-axis. But the Ranging is lost.]

But the problem is the ranging of the data lost. I need different range for two dataset.

I tried to adjust the width of the bars after drawing the chart

like

```
var g3 =  d3.selectAll ('.bars1Wrap .nv-groups .nv-series-0 rect') 
                             .attr("width", function(d){ return d/2;});
```

But no Success...
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, nvd3 is buggy on `multiChart`, when you select type **"bar"** for the two visualization dataset that need to be displayed.

What i am saying is that instead of this

```
testdata[0].type = "bar";
testdata[0].yAxis = 1;
testdata[1].type = "bar";
testdata[1].yAxis = 2;
```

had it been

```
testdata[0].type = "line";
testdata[0].yAxis = 1;
testdata[1].type = "bar";
testdata[1].yAxis = 2;
```

It works fine.

Thus in order to have two bar charts unstacked.
Need to do some out of box tweaking, call this function post chart is rendered.

```
function resetBarSize(d1){
      //get the width of the bar, and make it half
      var w2 = d3.select(".bars2Wrap .nv-bar").attr("width")/2;
      if (!d1){
        //initial load d1 will be undefined
        //in that case make all the bars half
        d3.selectAll(".bars1Wrap .nv-bar").style("width", w2);
        d3.selectAll(".bars2Wrap .nv-bar").style("width", w2);
        //translate the last bar so that there is no overlapping
        d3.selectAll(".bars2Wrap .nv-bar")[0].forEach(function(d){
          var t = d3.transform(d3.select(d).attr("transform")),
          x = t.translate[0] + w2,
          y = t.translate[1];
          d3.select(d).attr("transform", "translate(" + x +"," + y + ")");
        })        
      }else if (d1.yAxis ==2 && d1.disabled){
        //in this case axis 2 is disabled or not visible so make bar1 width double.
        d3.selectAll(".bars1Wrap .nv-bar").style("width", w2 *2);
      }else if (d1.yAxis ==1 && d1.disabled){
        //in this case axis 1 is disabled or not visible so make bar1 width double.
        d3.selectAll(".bars2Wrap .nv-bar").style("width", w2 *2);
      } else {
        //in this case axis both axis is present. Make all the bars half and translate bar 2 so that they don't overlap.

        d3.selectAll(".bars1Wrap .nv-bar").style("width", w2);
        d3.selectAll(".bars2Wrap .nv-bar").style("width", w2);
        d3.selectAll(".bars2Wrap .nv-bar")[0].forEach(function(d){
          var t = d3.transform(d3.select(d).attr("transform")),
          x = t.translate[0] + w2,
          y = t.translate[1];
          d3.select(d).attr("transform", "translate(" + x +"," + y + ")");
        })   
      }
      return;
    }
```

Now call this function after chart is rendered.

```
nv.dispatch.on('render_end', function(newState) {
  resetBarSize();
  chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendClick', function(newState) {
      chart.update();
      setTimeout(function(){resetBarSize(newState)});
});
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3v29V92H0D9b1tu2pVd?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks in advance for a great solution. One more problem I found on the code that if I turn off one legend the bar must come to its full width. Also in my situation I cannot call a second function after drawing the chart. Anyway I will modify nvd3 code to do this thing. Thank you for guide me towards a direction  to find a final solution. I hope this answer will be usefull to others also.

Comment: Please check my edited answer, my code now makes the bar full width, when legend is off.